# Order array based on relative time (not a time stamp) in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time

I have an array of events... each event has a key called "time". The "time" key stores a string such as "8:00 AM" or "6:00 PM".

I need to order this array based on that time key. How would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime()` can parse things like `8:00 AM`. It is your friend.

```
function cmp_func($a, $b) {
    $atime = strtotime($a['time']);
    $btime = strtotime($b['time']);
    if($atime == $btime) return 0;
    return ($atime < $btime) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($your_array, 'cmp_func');
```

Note that if the array(s) you're sorting in this fashion are very large, it may be worth it to store the value from `strtotime()` as part of the array beforehand, to reduce the number of calls to it overall.

Comment: Okay... but how do I sort a multidimensional array based on the index "time"? Remember that "time" isn't unique, as multiple events can have the same start time.

Comment: Hmm... thank you, one more question... I am using this in a class based system... so I would have: public function cmp_func($a, $b)... how would I use usort to call cmp_func as part of $this->cmp_func?

Comment: You can pass an array of strings to resolve the namespace (you'll want to make the comparison function a static function): `usort($your_array, array('ClassName', 'member_func_name'));` If, however, you didn't want to make it static (or didn't want to refer to the class name), you *can* pass `$this` as the first element of the array: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback

Comment: I cant seem to get this working... instead of getting the sorted array, I get the value "1".

Comment: `usort()` sorts the array in place. The return value from `usort()` is just a `TRUE`/`FALSE` success value (hence why you're getting 1 == `TRUE` for success). Look at your original array, rather than looking at the return value.

Answer (score 0):

[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) sort function, one off the comments

```
$array[0]['name']  = 'Chris';
$array[0]['phone'] = '3971095';
$array[0]['year']  = '1978';
$array[0]['address'] = 'Street 1';

$array[1]['name']  = 'Breanne';
$array[1]['phone'] = '3766350';
$array[1]['year']  = '1990';
$array[1]['address'] = 'Street 2';

$array[2]['name']  = 'Dusty';
$array[2]['phone'] = '1541120';
$array[2]['year']  = '1982';
$array[2]['address'] = 'Street 3';

function multisort($array, $sort_by, $key1, $key2=NULL, $key3=NULL, $key4=NULL, $key5=NULL, $key6=NULL){
    // sort by ?
    foreach ($array as $pos =>  $val)
        $tmp_array[$pos] = $val[$sort_by];
    asort($tmp_array);

    // display however you want
    foreach ($tmp_array as $pos =>  $val){
        $return_array[$pos][$sort_by] = $array[$pos][$sort_by];
        $return_array[$pos][$key1] = $array[$pos][$key1];
        if (isset($key2)){
            $return_array[$pos][$key2] = $array[$pos][$key2];
            }
        if (isset($key3)){
            $return_array[$pos][$key3] = $array[$pos][$key3];
            }
        if (isset($key4)){
            $return_array[$pos][$key4] = $array[$pos][$key4];
            }
        if (isset($key5)){
            $return_array[$pos][$key5] = $array[$pos][$key5];
            }
        if (isset($key6)){
            $return_array[$pos][$key6] = $array[$pos][$key6];
            }
        }
    return $return_array;
    }

//usage (only enter the keys you want sorted):

$sorted = multisort($array,'year','name','phone','address');
print_r($sorted);

//output:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [year] => 1978 [name] => Chris [phone] => 3971095 [address] => Street 1 ) [2] => Array ( [year] => 1982 [name] => Dusty [phone] => 1541120 [address] => Street 3 ) [1] => Array ( [year] => 1990 [name] => Breanne [phone] => 3766350 [address] => Street 2 ) )
```